# Trying to figure out Sgn function values

Tags: functional-analysis

I have a question about sgn function.  I know it has one of the three values (-1, 0 ,1) as here [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function).  I am reading a paper and it applies sgn function as follows:

```
 F = sgn(1-((|A∩B|)/(|A∪B|)))
```

My question is that, here `F` will be always positive! `F≥0`.
But they confirm that some times it will be positive and some times it will be negative.

Is it possible to get negative values? If yes then please explain.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $| \cdot |$ denotes cardinality or size of a set, then $|A \cap B|$ and $|A \cup B|$ are both non-negative, so here the sgn will never return a negative value.